# Get column names from blank stored procedure data set

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm currently writing a small app that takes data provided by an SQL stored procedure and makes it available for easy export for non-tech savvy users. I'm trying to make this as generic as possible, in that you should be able to plug in just about any SP and follow my template to have an export utility. I'd like to add a way to get the column names before running the SP from the SP itself. I had assumed you could just run the SP with impossible values so nothing is returned, then get the columns from the resulting VB.NET DataTable. However, if there is no data returned, the column names aren't returned either. How can I get the column names from the SP without having to hard-code them?

Comment: Are Table-Valued User-Defined Functions
 an option? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx Otherwise: `SELECT Column_Name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE Table_Schema = 'dbo' and Table_Name = 'TableName'`

Comment: Unfortunately, not in this case :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are [Table-Valued User-Defined Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx) an option?

Otherwise:

```
SELECT Column_Name 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE Table_Schema = 'dbo' and Table_Name = 'Table_Name'
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx

**Edit**:

> Even empty data sets pass the columns to an SqlDataReader. 
>   So, if you're getting a reader from the SqlCommand object, 
>   call GetSchemaTable() on the reader to get a DataTable 
>   with column metadata. 
>   The first column of each row is the name of the return column.

Comment: Solved it, but I can't post my own answer yet! Even empty data sets pass the columns to an SqlDataReader. So, if you're getting a reader from the SqlCommand object, call GetSchemaTable() on the reader to get a DataTable with column metadata. The first column of each row is the name of the return column.

Comment: @wrsenn: I've edited my answer accordingly. Pleased to hear that you got it to work.